# Navigating from TableViewCell to another View with performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to navigate from a tableviewcell to another view by the cell's path.
I am using the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if (indexPath == 0) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToKnutene" sender:self];
}
```

As you might understand, this did not work. 
Keep in mind that i am fairly new to xcode and objective-c.

In my head what this does is performing a segue to another view if the top cell in my tableview is pressed/released. And this is also what i want to do.

Comment: An easier method, particularly if you're using a static table layout, is to create the segue directly in interface builder.  Just ctrl-drag from the cell to the target view controller and done.

Comment: That was my initial thought, but i am reusing the cell that i created in my storyboard to create more cells from an array.

Comment: Then see the answers below, particularly @lootsch.  Currently you're comparing the NSIndexPath pointer to zero (nil) which will never be true.  What you're really interested in is the section and row properties of the indexPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `NSIndexPath` consists of a `row` and a `section`.
So you probably want to use

```
if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
```

Comment: So by setting indexPath == 0 i am not setting both .section and .row equal to 0?

Comment: No, you're comparing the value of the pointer to nil, not the values of the properties.  Essentially you're asking does this box exist, not does this box contain a white egg.

Comment: Makes sense! lootsch's answer fixed my problem. I guess I was not THAT wrong.